# Prime factors output - what's the issue?

Tags: c++, primes

I am entering the [UVA online programming competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UVa_Online_Judge), and am working on a solution for UVA 583 (Prime Factors).

I recently made a Java solution for this that got accepted. When I tried translating it to C++, it always got WA ("wrong answer") even though for each test case I make, both programs output the same answer.

Can anyone point out what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int primes [4792];
void factorize(int x1){
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<4792;i++){
        int x2 = primes[i];
        while(x1%x2==0){
            if(c!=0)
                cout<<" x ";
            cout<<x2;
            c++;
            x1/=x2;
        }
    }
    if(x1>1 && c!=0){
        cout<<" x "<<x1;
    }
    if(c==0)
        cout<<x1;
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    primes[0]=2;
    primes[1]=3;
    int count = 2;
    for(int i=5; i<46340;i+=2){
        if(i%6 != 1 && i%6 != 5)
            continue;
        int limit = (int)sqrt((double)i);
        bool isPrime = true;
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
            if(primes[j]<limit){
                if(i%primes[j]==0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isPrime){
            primes[count]=i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    int x = 0;
    cin>>x;
    while(x!=0){
        string out;
        cout<<x<<" = " ;
        int x1 = x;
        if(x<0){
            cout<< "-1 x ";
            x1*=-1;
        }
        factorize(x1);
        cin>>x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do WA and UVA mean?

Comment: Please at least show a link to the problem spec. Also, since you recently made a Java solution for this that got accepted, how about diffing it with your C++ solution side-by-side? At lease someone could perform equivalence checking.

Comment: @segfaulter09: I've no idea of how they mark these things, but stylistically your code is horrible. Try and break the problem down into pieces and code each piece as a separate function.

Comment: @jahhaj yeah I think it really has something to do with the way i present the output...might have an extra space somewhere which i can't detect

Comment: @segfaulter09: You're mixing printf and cout, perhaps not a good idea.

Comment: @jahhaj removed the printf, still the same problem ahaha. darnit

Comment: I agree with walrii - the terms "WA", "UVA" and "got accepted" are unclear. I find that these mean, respectively, "wrong answer", "[UVA Online Judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UVa_Online_Judge)" and "acceptance" is the status of whether a submitted program has been accepted. This appears to be an online problem-solving contest. -1

Answer (score 1):

```
while((double)x1/(double)x2 == (double)(x1/x2)){
```

That is almost always a bad idea. Due to the limited precision of floating point operations, you can end up with cases where in the mathematical sense the two are exactly equivalent, but for which the test above yields false.

Comment: I removed the double-casting comparison and replaced it with modulo and am still getting a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

in your `factorize(int x1)`, just above `while`, add `if (x2*x2 > x1) break;`.

in your `main()`, `if(primes[j]<limit){` should be using  `<=` and it should have `else` clause with `{break;}` in it.  With `<` in place of `<=` I'm surprised it worked for you in Java.

As it is, with `<` there, your code does not recognize the top 46 primes below 46340 - it puts them *past the array end*<sup>1</sup> where they remain out of reach. Writing past array's end is bad in itself.

<sup>1</sup> that is because it falsely recognizes the squares of primes as prime numbers, and there are 46 such squares between 5 and 46340.

Comment: Can't have had the `<` in Java, Java would've raised an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since the array has space only for the primes, not the squares of primes.

Comment: Well, the array size must be adjusted, but otherwise, now that `%` is used, that would produce the correct factorisations.

Comment: (Daniel responded to my comment that I quickly deleted, suggesting half jokingly that loop in `factorize` be changed to work up to 4838 to compensate). But changing `<` to `<=` is easier and *proper* thing to do here.

Comment: @Daniel the joke was that if it worked without segfaulting so far, it could continue working without the array size adjustment... but then I though it was a *bad* joke. :)

Comment: Yes, it could indeed. And yes, that's scary, as UB should be.